# Erro ao calcular media com vetor C

Tags: array, c++

Estou tentando calcular a media de notas de um vetor em que fiz alocação dinamica, porem aparece o seguinte erro:

line 66- [Error] invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

line 66- [Error] too few arguments to function 'int media(int, int*)'

```
#include <stdio.h>


#include <stdlib.h>

int media(int n, int *pN);

int main(void) {
    
    int *pA, *pN; //criando ponteiros para os vetores
    int i,j;
    int qtdAlunos,notas;
    int media_notas;



//Aqui dou inicio ao vetor de alunos.
    printf("Numero de alunos: ");
    scanf("%d", &qtdAlunos);



    pA = (int *)(malloc(qtdAlunos * sizeof(int)));

    
    for (i = 0; i< qtdAlunos; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite o numero referentes aos alunos: [%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &pA[i]);
    }

//percorrendo o vetor para mostar os valores armazenados
    for (i = 0; i< qtdAlunos; i++)
    {
        printf("\nAlunos: [%d] = %d", i, pA[i]);
        
    }


//Agora estarei criando valores do vetor nota

    
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Quantas notas? ");
    scanf("%d", &notas);
    
  
    
    pN = (int*)(malloc(notas * sizeof(int)));
        
    for (j = 0; j<notas; j++)
    {
        printf("Digite as notas: [%d] = ", j, pN[j]);
        scanf("%d", &pN[j]);
    }
    

    //percorrendo o vetor para mostrar valores de notas
    
    for (j = 0; j<notas; j++)
    {
        printf("\nNotas: [%d] = %d", j,pN[j]);
    }
    
//chamada da função
    media_notas = media(pN);
    
    scanf ("\nMedia = %.1f \n", media_notas);
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    
}

int media (int n, int *pN)
{
    int j;
    int m = 0, soma = 0;
    
    for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    soma = soma + pN[j];
    
    m= soma / n;
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Note que você utiliza `media_notas = media(pN);` mas definiu a função media com 2 parâmetros, a quantidade de elementos e o array, creio que deva ser: `media_notas = media(notas, pN);`.

Answer (score 2):

1. O primeiro erro acontece porque você definiu a função "media" como recebendo dois parâmetros, um inteiro e um ponteiro para inteiro. No entanto, a chamada da função é feita passando apenas um parâmetro, que é um ponteiro para inteiro, sendo que o primeiro parâmetro deveria ser um inteiro. O segundo erro ocorre porque a função espera dois parâmetros, mas apenas um foi passado. Para resolver esses erros, é necessário corrigir a chamada da função:

   media_notas = media(notas, pN);

Além disso, o código tem alguns erros de lógica:

2. A função "media" deveria ser do tipo *double* ou *float*, já que uma média aritmética pode conter números depois da vírgula;
3. A variável "m", dentro da função "media", também deve ser do tipo *double* ou *float*, pois é ela que conterá o valor de retorno da função;
4. A variável "media_notas", dentro da função "main", também deve ser do tipo *double* ou *float", pois ela receberá o valor de retorno da função "media";
5. Provavelmente por engano, você escreveu

   ```
   scanf ("\nMedia = %.1f \n", media_notas);
   ```

   para mostrar a média das notas, sendo que o comando utilizado deveria ser o *printf*:

   ```
   printf ("\nMedia = %.1lf \n", media_notas);
   ```

Além disso, havia um *%d" a mais na linha:

```
printf("Digite as notas: [%d] = ", j, pN[j]);
```

Você só deveria mostrar o valor de *j*, já que o valor de *pN[j]* ainda será lido:

O código corrigido completo fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>


#include <stdlib.h>

double media(int n, int *pN);

int main(void) {
    
    int *pA, *pN; //criando ponteiros para os vetores
    int i,j;
    int qtdAlunos,notas;
    double media_notas;



//Aqui dou inicio ao vetor de alunos.
    printf("Numero de alunos: ");
    scanf("%d", &qtdAlunos);



    pA = (int *)(malloc(qtdAlunos * sizeof(int)));

    
    for (i = 0; i< qtdAlunos; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite o numero referentes aos alunos: [%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &pA[i]);
    }

//percorrendo o vetor para mostar os valores armazenados
    for (i = 0; i< qtdAlunos; i++)
    {
        printf("\nAlunos: [%d] = %d", i, pA[i]);
        
    }


//Agora estarei criando valores do vetor nota

    
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Quantas notas? ");
    scanf("%d", &notas);
    
  
    
    pN = (int*)(malloc(notas * sizeof(int)));
        
    for (j = 0; j<notas; j++)
    {
        printf("Digite as notas : [%d] = ", j);
        scanf("%d", &pN[j]);
    }
    

    //percorrendo o vetor para mostrar valores de notas
    
    for (j = 0; j<notas; j++)
    {
        printf("\nNotas: [%d] = %d", j,pN[j]);
    }
    
//chamada da função
    media_notas = media(notas, pN);
    
    printf ("\nMedia = %.1lf \n", media_notas);
    
    return 0;
    
}

double media (int n, int *pN)
{
    int j;
    int soma = 0;
    double m;
    
    for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
     soma = soma + pN[j];
    
    m = (double)soma / n;

    system("pause");
    return m;
}
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/@Jvsierra_/TameOddGenerics#main.c)